# Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges to some $f$ in mean.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_m:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be defined as for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\exists m = 2^n + k,\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,2^n-1\}$
$$
f_{2^n+k}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges to some $f$ in mean, find $f$ explicitly and then show that $\{f_n\}$ diverges pointwise.

By "converges to $f$ in mean," we use the following definition:

A sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$, with $f_n:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, converges in mean to a function $f$ if and only if
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_a^b [f_n(x) - f]^2 dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0
$$

Comment: Hint: what is $\int_a^b |f_n(x)|^2\; dx$?

Comment: I'm afraid to just say "I have no clue," but to be completely honest...I really don't have a clue. My professor touched very lightly on the subject of convergence in mean, and now has asked for quite a few questions regarding it. It doesn't help that there aren't very many online sources to help explain the concept either.

Comment: We're taking $a=0$ and $b=1$ here. $f_n(x)$ is $1$ on a certain interval, and $0$ everywhere else.  You really can't compute $\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2\; dx$?

Comment: Oh jeez... I feel dumb now. I guess it's just been a long week. $\frac{1}{2^n}$, correct?

Answer (score 1):

For the mean convergence, follow Robert Israel's hint.

For the pointwise divergence  : what can you say about $(f_{2^n+2^n-1}(1))_n$ and $(f_{2^n}(1))_n$ ? and what can you say about a sequence which has at least two subsequences that converge to a different value ?